# Schedule Laravel task based on variable value from .env file

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I've built a Laravel system that schedules an artisan command to run daily at a specific time based off of a variable which is set in the .env file. This is because we need to set differing times for each installation of this syten.

**.env**

```
DEBTOR_EMAIL_TIME="12:30"
```

**Kernel.php**

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('commandt:make --email=test@test.com')->dailyAt(env('DEBTOR_EMAIL_TIME'));
}
```

If I hard-code a time into the dailyAt() method, the scheduler will either tell me there a no jobs queued to run or the job runs at the specified time.

When I use a variable, I get no output.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: Use a `config()` variable instead

Comment: yes, you should use config variable and get env data in config

Comment: have you tried to var_dump that env variable and checked that those double quotes are part of the string like `string(7) ""12:30""`

Comment: @brombeer I've switched to using config() and calling the env variables in the config file to no avail. I've logged that the variable does indeed return the correct time string.